# Random Evens function

Tags: python, function, random, integer

I'm fairly new to coding, picking it up as a hobby, because its so far, fun, engaging, and challenging. Started out learning Python.

Just for the heck of it, I'm trying to write a function that will generate random integers, only print the even integers, and stop when it finally prints the number 28 (picked it at random.)

I've tried everything I could think of to get the function to loop, but the only thing I've been able to do successfully is just print out a single random even number once before the function stops.

Is there a way to have a function iterate through randint generated numbers between a user defined range, e.g.(0,x), and then apply if/elif/else's to the number(s) generated?

I've probably tried rewriting that same function 30-40 times, but I either get a single even number, a myriad of syntax errors, or some blue script that says "random.randint object at- and then a bunch of numbers.."???

Perhaps I just need to keep delving deeper into tutorials to find the answer, but this seemed like a more productive option. Perhaps there's something I'm not thinking of, or perhaps the concepts I need to employ I just haven't learned yet. Any advice/tips/actual lines of code GREATLY APPRECIATED!

Thanks in advance
Mike

Comment: Please include "_everything I could think of_" (preferably with code) in your question.

Comment: @DyZ: Well, ideally not *everything*; the "minimal" part of a [MCVE] is rather important.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Well, at least _something_.

Comment: Personally I would love to see the 30-40 different functions that are all incorrect. Now that would be a feat worth seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I was using the for loop incorrectly, and placing the num = randint(0,x) in the wrong place(wrong line). I've included the final function:

```
from random import randint
def random_even(x):
   for i in range(x):
      num = randint(0,x)
      if num==28:
         print(num,"\n DONE")
         break
      elif num%2==0:
         print(num)
```

Comment: What happens when `X < 28`?

Comment: Wether x is less than or greater than 28, the function only prints the even integers, and breaks once it randomly prints 28. If it does not reach 28, it continues to print even integers in range(x). My next puzzle is to try and implement .shuffle or some other function so it does not print duplicates of any integer. Also: I apologize that the code got squeezed together in my comment. I though it would stay seperated.

Comment: Right. I'm nit picking the **breaks once it randomly prints 28** in that `randint(0,26)` can't ever print `28`.  So while the code works, it doesn't do _exactly_ what you said in English it would do.  A more correct statement would be  **breaks once it has printed X even numbers OR randomly prints 28**.   I'm not meaning to harass you on this.  I'm trying to help you understand, as a new coder, how hard it can be to turn imprecise English into completely correct Python.  Doubt I'm making the point well, though.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the constructive criticisms. I randomly chose 28 just cause I wanted to make it pick (some number), which you could change to conceivably anything you wanted. Just trying to challenge myself more and more as I keep learning. I don't think I've even scratched 2%... :D XD